# How to get a list of numbers out of an awk output in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk, dataset

ok so I am currently in the process of making a very basic bash script to search a jsonl file of mario maker levels with their id's, and then converting the found id's into the actual in game id's using a python script given to me (the database and explanation is in this reddit thread, im searching the courses.jsonl file https://www.reddit.com/r/MarioMaker/comments/wlkwp9/easily_searchable_database_of_super_mario_maker_1/)

with my current code, im able to search, seperate just the id's, then convert 1 id to the correct in game id. however, i am not sure how i would be able to convert all the id's found in the search separately. would it just be a for loop, or would i have to do something more complex? here is the code, any help would be appreciated, as most of my bash knowledge is very basic

```
#!/bin/sh
id=$(grep $1 /file/path/courses.jsonl | awk -F ',' '{print $1}' | awk -F ':' '{print $2}')


python3 /file/path/mmid.py $id
```

edit: here is the current mmid.py file, its basically the initial one i was given with the small change of just adding the id to an argument on runtime instead of asking for input after running

```
import struct
import hashlib
import hmac
import sys
idno = int(sys.argv[1])
key = hashlib.md5(b"9f2b4678").digest()
data = struct.pack("<Q", idno)
checksum = hmac.HMAC(key, data, 'md5').digest()
checksum = checksum[3:1:-1].hex().upper()
idstring = str.upper(hex(idno))[2:]
for y in range(8 - len(idstring)):
    idstring = '0' + str(idstring)
code = str(checksum) + '0000' + str(idstring)
print(code)
```

edit 2: i was asked for an example of the courses.jsonl file, so here is one entry. they all look like this, the important thing im grabbing here is the id, which is the first part

```
{"id":69558108,"retrieval_date":"2021-06-05T08:04:59.154776Z","url":"https://d2sno3mhmk1ekx.cloudfront.net/10.WUP_AMAJ_datastore/ds/1/data/00069558108-00001?Expires=1625472299&Signature=BqxLU18d~4rV4FeHNN-Sm2dbKqKyLhS5qX2liHPqr3MN9Y0Fgt5GCYCXrseFt-tinj4LVjrtMIWZW4G1ijj4FSHQyXN9OoW3PfyZbSuatl9~aNHLPtCCBfMDm7HmF~Njry1pvFjvmeMTJf4ZlUTrKIJF00gfA~2Mu2K1qjIR4yqSQCyxsxG61J~KG3CQMVJUKnbdGupeHN5-nigDqZ3EbT3-odEmjJsq04wb8K98iNMVHKINg8MZwuWHtEtECGWWqvhAvkdRDj6ZZQxAPW1fwxkLJBY4PSRW28A20T-lcq0CDDeU4yFUzeeE6GqFV0xvwj2IOFrlWVOo3McmE21HqA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJUYKVK3BE6ZPNZBQ","stars":1,"course_name":"hello kitty saves xmas by Lario\u2122","creator":{"pid":1745383521,"nnid":"realdealLario","mii_data":"QlBGQwAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAwAAQMHCaSxE5iEQ2lRGSOgTQXuGIgAAiANMAGEAcgBpAG8AIiEAAAAAAAAAACNiKABCAQPHRBgLM0cQDg8RsCoAACIAUkhQAABlAAAAcgBlAGEAawAAAAAAAAAAAO1hAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQ="},"upload_time":"2021-03-30T22:59:39Z","user_plays":2,"clears":1,"total_attempts":5,"failures":4,"world_record":{"best_time_player":{"pid":1747253384,"nnid":"ilovesnowandcold","mii_data":"QlBGQwAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAwAAEGpkmkWgRBCggeC0lA/Q2aSlewAAghVLAGUAaQB0AGgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAsVAAAsApJuRBgnNEcYhhIOaA8AACnQUUhQSwBlAGkAdABoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJLUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAE="},"first_complete_player":{"pid":1747253384,"nnid":"ilovesnowandcold","mii_data":"QlBGQwAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAwAAEGpkmkWgRBCggeC0lA/Q2aSlewAAghVLAGUAaQB0AGgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAsVAAAsApJuRBgnNEcYhhIOaA8AACnQUUhQSwBlAGkAdABoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJLUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAE="},"best_time_ms":13245,"created_time":"2021-03-30T23:52:40Z","updated_time":"2021-03-30T23:52:40Z"}}
```

I should clarify, this jsonl file is over 16gb of raw text

Comment: Are you allowed to alter `mmid.py` or it must remain as-is AT ANY PRICE?

Comment: i am able to edit mmid.py yes, i will post the current version of it in the post

Comment: Can you give a sample of the file `courses.jsonl`?

Comment: added an entry from courses.jsonl in an edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it entirely within python:

**EDIT**: Now with matching `course_name`

```py
import hashlib
import hmac
import jsonlines
import re
import struct
import sys

course_name = str(sys.argv[1])
idno = -1
reader = jsonlines.Reader(sys.stdin)
for obj in reader:
    if re.search(course_name, obj["course_name"]):
        idno = int(obj["id"])
        break
if idno > -1:
    key = hashlib.md5(b"9f2b4678").digest()
    data = struct.pack("<Q", idno)
    checksum = hmac.HMAC(key, data, "md5").digest()
    checksum = checksum[3:1:-1].hex().upper()
    idstring = str.upper(hex(idno))[2:]
    for y in range(8 - len(idstring)):
        idstring = "0" + str(idstring)
    code = str(checksum) + "0000" + str(idstring)
    print(code)
else:
    print("Cannot match course_name: %s\n" % course_name)
```

Usage example:

```bash
$ ./bin/python3 ./mmid.py kitty < ./courses.jsonl
7AC9000004255F5C
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can modify the code, like:

```
#!/bin/bash


ids=$(grep $1 /file/path/courses.jsonl | awk -F ',' '{print $1}' | awk -F ':' '{print $2}')


for id in $ids; do
    
    python3 /file/path/mmid.py $id
done
```

Comment: Just one question. Why involve Bash, and awk two times rather than read the json lines file within the python script itself using the dedicated jsonline library here? https://jsonlines.org/examples/

Comment: tbh, simply because i am learning bash, and because i know more bash. could probably do the whole thing in python but wanted to do it in bash

Comment: You should copy/paste that into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it'll tell you about.

Comment: `grep $1 /file/path/courses.jsonl` is extremely fragile as it's using an unquoted argument and so that'll undergo globbing, word splitting, and file name expansion courtesy of the shell before `grep` even sees it and then `grep` is doing a whole line regexp match with it's argument(s) when you want a literal string full-field match on one specific input field. The net result is you'll get matches that you don't expect and not get matches that you do expect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I must note that working with JSON objects like so

```
grep $1 /file/path/courses.jsonl | awk -F ',' '{print $1}' | awk -F ':' '{print $2}'
```

is extremely fragile and happens to work due to order inside JSON object, meanwhile according to [RFC 8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259)

> An object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value pairs,
> where a name is a string and a value is a string, number, boolean,
> null, object, or array.

therefore following two

```
{"id":123,"name":"somename"}
{"name":"somename","id":123}
```

are equivalent but would give *different* result if you would shove it into

```
| awk -F ',' '{print $1}' | awk -F ':' '{print $2}'
```

You might use tools for dealing with JSON like `jq` to lessen fragility, consider that

```
echo -e '{"id":123,"name":"somename"}\n{"name":"somename","id":123}' | jq '.id'
```

gives output

```
123
123
```

Now you have one id per line, your `mmid.py` might be altered to take ids from standard input following way

```
import struct
import hashlib
import hmac
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    idno = int(line)
    key = hashlib.md5(b"9f2b4678").digest()
    data = struct.pack("<Q", idno)
    checksum = hmac.HMAC(key, data, 'md5').digest()
    checksum = checksum[3:1:-1].hex().upper()
    idstring = str.upper(hex(idno))[2:]
    for y in range(8 - len(idstring)):
        idstring = '0' + str(idstring)
    code = str(checksum) + '0000' + str(idstring)
    print(code)
```

and then you might assemble whole thing as follows, let `courses.jsonl` content be

```
{"id":69558108,"retrieval_date":"2021-06-05T08:04:59.154776Z","url":"https://d2sno3mhmk1ekx.cloudfront.net/10.WUP_AMAJ_datastore/ds/1/data/00069558108-00001?Expires=1625472299&Signature=BqxLU18d~4rV4FeHNN-Sm2dbKqKyLhS5qX2liHPqr3MN9Y0Fgt5GCYCXrseFt-tinj4LVjrtMIWZW4G1ijj4FSHQyXN9OoW3PfyZbSuatl9~aNHLPtCCBfMDm7HmF~Njry1pvFjvmeMTJf4ZlUTrKIJF00gfA~2Mu2K1qjIR4yqSQCyxsxG61J~KG3CQMVJUKnbdGupeHN5-nigDqZ3EbT3-odEmjJsq04wb8K98iNMVHKINg8MZwuWHtEtECGWWqvhAvkdRDj6ZZQxAPW1fwxkLJBY4PSRW28A20T-lcq0CDDeU4yFUzeeE6GqFV0xvwj2IOFrlWVOo3McmE21HqA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJUYKVK3BE6ZPNZBQ","stars":1,"course_name":"hello kitty saves xmas by Lario\u2122","creator":{"pid":1745383521,"nnid":"realdealLario","mii_data":"QlBGQwAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAwAAQMHCaSxE5iEQ2lRGSOgTQXuGIgAAiANMAGEAcgBpAG8AIiEAAAAAAAAAACNiKABCAQPHRBgLM0cQDg8RsCoAACIAUkhQAABlAAAAcgBlAGEAawAAAAAAAAAAAO1hAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQ="},"upload_time":"2021-03-30T22:59:39Z","user_plays":2,"clears":1,"total_attempts":5,"failures":4,"world_record":{"best_time_player":{"pid":1747253384,"nnid":"ilovesnowandcold","mii_data":"QlBGQwAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAwAAEGpkmkWgRBCggeC0lA/Q2aSlewAAghVLAGUAaQB0AGgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAsVAAAsApJuRBgnNEcYhhIOaA8AACnQUUhQSwBlAGkAdABoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJLUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAE="},"first_complete_player":{"pid":1747253384,"nnid":"ilovesnowandcold","mii_data":"QlBGQwAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAwAAEGpkmkWgRBCggeC0lA/Q2aSlewAAghVLAGUAaQB0AGgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAsVAAAsApJuRBgnNEcYhhIOaA8AACnQUUhQSwBlAGkAdABoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJLUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAE="},"best_time_ms":13245,"created_time":"2021-03-30T23:52:40Z","updated_time":"2021-03-30T23:52:40Z"}}
{"id":69558108,"retrieval_date":"2021-06-05T08:04:59.154776Z","url":"https://d2sno3mhmk1ekx.cloudfront.net/10.WUP_AMAJ_datastore/ds/1/data/00069558108-00001?Expires=1625472299&Signature=BqxLU18d~4rV4FeHNN-Sm2dbKqKyLhS5qX2liHPqr3MN9Y0Fgt5GCYCXrseFt-tinj4LVjrtMIWZW4G1ijj4FSHQyXN9OoW3PfyZbSuatl9~aNHLPtCCBfMDm7HmF~Njry1pvFjvmeMTJf4ZlUTrKIJF00gfA~2Mu2K1qjIR4yqSQCyxsxG61J~KG3CQMVJUKnbdGupeHN5-nigDqZ3EbT3-odEmjJsq04wb8K98iNMVHKINg8MZwuWHtEtECGWWqvhAvkdRDj6ZZQxAPW1fwxkLJBY4PSRW28A20T-lcq0CDDeU4yFUzeeE6GqFV0xvwj2IOFrlWVOo3McmE21HqA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJUYKVK3BE6ZPNZBQ","stars":1,"course_name":"hello kitty saves xmas by Lario\u2122","creator":{"pid":1745383521,"nnid":"realdealLario","mii_data":"QlBGQwAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAwAAQMHCaSxE5iEQ2lRGSOgTQXuGIgAAiANMAGEAcgBpAG8AIiEAAAAAAAAAACNiKABCAQPHRBgLM0cQDg8RsCoAACIAUkhQAABlAAAAcgBlAGEAawAAAAAAAAAAAO1hAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQ="},"upload_time":"2021-03-30T22:59:39Z","user_plays":2,"clears":1,"total_attempts":5,"failures":4,"world_record":{"best_time_player":{"pid":1747253384,"nnid":"ilovesnowandcold","mii_data":"QlBGQwAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAwAAEGpkmkWgRBCggeC0lA/Q2aSlewAAghVLAGUAaQB0AGgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAsVAAAsApJuRBgnNEcYhhIOaA8AACnQUUhQSwBlAGkAdABoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJLUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAE="},"first_complete_player":{"pid":1747253384,"nnid":"ilovesnowandcold","mii_data":"QlBGQwAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAwAAEGpkmkWgRBCggeC0lA/Q2aSlewAAghVLAGUAaQB0AGgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAsVAAAsApJuRBgnNEcYhhIOaA8AACnQUUhQSwBlAGkAdABoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJLUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAE="},"best_time_ms":13245,"created_time":"2021-03-30T23:52:40Z","updated_time":"2021-03-30T23:52:40Z"}}
{"id":69558108,"retrieval_date":"2021-06-05T08:04:59.154776Z","url":"https://d2sno3mhmk1ekx.cloudfront.net/10.WUP_AMAJ_datastore/ds/1/data/00069558108-00001?Expires=1625472299&Signature=BqxLU18d~4rV4FeHNN-Sm2dbKqKyLhS5qX2liHPqr3MN9Y0Fgt5GCYCXrseFt-tinj4LVjrtMIWZW4G1ijj4FSHQyXN9OoW3PfyZbSuatl9~aNHLPtCCBfMDm7HmF~Njry1pvFjvmeMTJf4ZlUTrKIJF00gfA~2Mu2K1qjIR4yqSQCyxsxG61J~KG3CQMVJUKnbdGupeHN5-nigDqZ3EbT3-odEmjJsq04wb8K98iNMVHKINg8MZwuWHtEtECGWWqvhAvkdRDj6ZZQxAPW1fwxkLJBY4PSRW28A20T-lcq0CDDeU4yFUzeeE6GqFV0xvwj2IOFrlWVOo3McmE21HqA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJUYKVK3BE6ZPNZBQ","stars":1,"course_name":"hello kitty saves xmas by Lario\u2122","creator":{"pid":1745383521,"nnid":"realdealLario","mii_data":"QlBGQwAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAwAAQMHCaSxE5iEQ2lRGSOgTQXuGIgAAiANMAGEAcgBpAG8AIiEAAAAAAAAAACNiKABCAQPHRBgLM0cQDg8RsCoAACIAUkhQAABlAAAAcgBlAGEAawAAAAAAAAAAAO1hAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQ="},"upload_time":"2021-03-30T22:59:39Z","user_plays":2,"clears":1,"total_attempts":5,"failures":4,"world_record":{"best_time_player":{"pid":1747253384,"nnid":"ilovesnowandcold","mii_data":"QlBGQwAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAwAAEGpkmkWgRBCggeC0lA/Q2aSlewAAghVLAGUAaQB0AGgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAsVAAAsApJuRBgnNEcYhhIOaA8AACnQUUhQSwBlAGkAdABoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJLUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAE="},"first_complete_player":{"pid":1747253384,"nnid":"ilovesnowandcold","mii_data":"QlBGQwAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAwAAEGpkmkWgRBCggeC0lA/Q2aSlewAAghVLAGUAaQB0AGgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAsVAAAsApJuRBgnNEcYhhIOaA8AACnQUUhQSwBlAGkAdABoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJLUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAE="},"best_time_ms":13245,"created_time":"2021-03-30T23:52:40Z","updated_time":"2021-03-30T23:52:40Z"}}
```

and `mmid.py` content be as shown above, then

```
jq '.id' courses.jsonl | python3 mmid.py
```

gives output

```
7AC9000004255F5C
7AC9000004255F5C
7AC9000004255F5C
```

Explanation: I added `for` loop, which body encompasses everything from `idno =` ... to end and changed idno line so it is compute from line of standard input (`sys.stdin`) rather than 1st command line argument (`sys.argv[1`]). Note: I repeated your sample input row to present that it works with many rows.

*(tested in jq-1.6 and Python 3.10.12)*